# Use S3 To Store ConfigMap

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-s3

I have a ConfigMap which stores Nginx configs and It is getting `size exceeded`. There are many site configs in there so I can't create multiple ConfigMaps.

I thought of using S3 to store ConfigMap, is it an option? If it is, how can one achieve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ConfigMaps in Kubernetes are [limited to 1Mib](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/#:%7E:text=The%20data%20stored%20in%20a,separate%20database%20or%20file%20service.). If your file could not be split or shrunk, I feel you should use a volume to store it using the storage class that your cloud vendor/subsystem offers you.

S3 is a good object store, but you can't store ConfigMaps in it.
You can't use it either to store volumes. You could use EBS and EFS (since we are talking about AWS products) based on access pattern that you want to achieve for this filesystem.

Comment: can we use EBS or EFS for config Map?

Comment: Nope, ConfigMap is a specific object that is stored in the KeyValue distributed datastore (es. Etcd) and so far we are not allowed to change where this object is stored.